# Bibliography does not sort correctly according to nyt

Tags: biblatex, biber, sorting

I am trying to cite 3 works of a common author and I expect that the will be sorted by Name,Year,Title, i.e, `sorting=nyt`. However, I do not get that result obviously as you can see:

[image]

I am not sure it does have to do with the fact that there are different bib type, e.g., book or article, or I am doing something wrong here. I would like to get the bibliography sorted as follow:
[Cohen, 2008]

[Cohen, 2003a]

[Cohen, 2003b]

Below you can find the minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[
fontsize=12pt,
paper=a4,
pagesize=auto,
BCOR=0mm,
DIV=12,
draft=false,
twoside=true,
numbers=noenddot,
parskip=half,
headsepline,
headinclude=false,
chapterprefix=true,
appendixprefix=true,
toc=listof,
toc=bibliography
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
natbib=false,
date=year,
refsection=none, %it was: chapter
isbn=false,doi=false,url=false,
maxalphanames=1,
giveninits= false,
firstinits=false,
abbreviate = false,
style=alphabetic,maxnames=99,minnames=99,maxbibnames=99,
sorting=nyt
]{biblatex}
\setlength{\bibhang}{0pt}

\renewcommand*{\labelalphaothers}{}

\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
    \labelelement{
        \field[final]{shorthand}
        \field{labelname}
        \field{label}
    }
    \labelelement{
        \literal{,\addhighpenspace}
    }
    \labelelement{
        \field{year}
    }
}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
    \printfield{volume}%
    \setunit*{\addnbspace}% NEW (optional); there's also \addnbthinspace
    \printfield{number}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{eid}}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{image}{%
    \printnames{author}%
    \newblock
    \printfield{year}%
    \newblock
    \printfield{title}%
    \newblock
    \printfield{type}%
    \addperiod\newunit\newblock
    \printlist{publisher}%
    \newblock
    \printfield{url}%
    \newblock
    \printfield{addendum}%
    \finentry}

\addbibresource{Janbib.bib}
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\fontsize{11}{14}\selectfont}
\begin{document}
    Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  \cite{Cohen2003}  \\    Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text    Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text    Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  \cite{BenestyBook2008_MicArray} \\ Text   Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text    Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text    Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  Text  \cite{CohenGannotBerdugo2003}.
    
\printbibliography  
    
    
\end{document}
```

and my Janbib.bib file look likes this:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\Janbib.bib}
@article{Cohen2003,
    Title                    = {Noise spectrum estimation in adverse environments: improved minima controlled recursive averaging},
    Author                   = {I. Cohen},
    Journal                  = {IEEE Trans. Speech and Audio Process.},
    Year                     = {2003},
    Pages                    = {466-475},
    Volume                   = {11},
    Owner                    = {mazarpour},
    Timestamp                = {2013.10.17}
}

@article{CohenGannotBerdugo2003,
    Title                    = {An integrated real-time beamforming and postfiltering system for nonstationary noise environments},
    Author                   = {I. Cohen  and S. Gannot  and B. Berdugo},
    Journal                  = {EURASIP J. Adv. Signal Process.},
    Year                     = {2003},
    Number                = {11},
    Pages                    = {1064-1073},
    Volume                   = {2003}
}


@inBook{BenestyBook2008_MicArray,
    Title                    = {Microphone Array Signal Processing},
    Author                 = {I. Cohen and S. Gannot},
    Editor                  = {J. Benesty and W. Kellermann},
    Pages                    = {39-67},
    Publisher                = {Springer-Verlag Berlin Heidelberg},
    Year                     = {2008},
    Address                  = {Berlin, Heidelberg},
    Booktitle                = {Conventional Beamforming Techniques}
}
\end{filecontents}
```

Comment: From the duplicate: your bibliography is sorted on all author names, so first _Cohen_, then _CohenGannot_, then _CohenGannotBerdugo_. You can sort on first author only using `labelalpha` and `sorting=anyt`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked perfectly!

Comment: It should be noted that `sorting=anyt,` is the default for `style=alphabetic,` and that the sorting scheme is explicitly overridden to `nyt` in the example. If the example had not set any sorting scheme at all, `anyt` would have been active from the start.